# Can HP ALM 12.50 is compatible with UFT 12.02?

Tags: hp-uft

When i try to establish the HP ALM (12.50 version) connection from UFT (12.02), getting below error:

> [HP.QC.InternalIntegration.Communication.SecureWebClient]could not see
>   cookie NSC_wh-iq-rvbmjuz-dfoufs-8080, errorcode=4317

Can any one help what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Both the tools with the version that you are specifying are NOT compatible with each other.
Here is the screenshot of Product Availability Matrix (PAM):

[image]

You can download this PAM from [**`this`**](https://softwaresupport.hpe.com/km/KM02546064/UFT_12.XX_PAM_pdf.pdf) link. You will need HP passport for it.